# Como faço para comparar valores entre duas tabelas e enviar e-mail caso tenha valor novo?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, vb.net

Meu sistema importa todos os dias arquivos CSVs de diversos diretórios em uma tabela chamada TB_ARQUIVO. Nesse arquivo, contém o nome do Hotel(Coluna HOTEL_NOME) e quatro tipos de Canais... SEGMENTO, ORIGEM, COMUNICACAO e VEICULO, fora outras colunas..

Tenho outras tabelas em que já tenho cadastrado previamente as informações que uso para pontuar os clientes. Ou seja, tenho a TB_HOTEl com todos os hotéis cadastrados que são comparados com o arquivo importado na coluna HOTEL_NOME. Assim como tenho as seguintes tabelas TB_SEGMENTO, TB_COMUNICACAO, TB_VEICULO e TB_ORIGEM.

As vezes recebo nomes de hotéis ou nome de canais que não estão cadastrados nessas tabelas. Com isso , tenho que cadastrar manualmente e reimportar o arquivo gerando muito trabalho.

Como faço para gerar um select que me traga todos os nomes dos hoteis + todos os canais e comparo com as tabelas já cadastradas com a finalidade de identificar novos hotéis e novos canais e enviá-los por e-mail ?

Tudo o que existir na TB_ARQUIVO nos campos HOTEL_NOME, SEGMENTO, COMUNICACAO, ORIGEM e VEICULO e não existir na TB_HOTEL, TB_SEGMENTO, TB_COMUNICACAO, TB_VEICULO e TB_ORIGEM deve ser enviado por e-mail.

Alguém conhece uma forma simples de fazer isso ?

Comment: Dê uma olhada aqui: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173041/not-in-vs-not-exists

Comment: Pode utilizar isso para slectionar os que não existem, agora sobre o email vc tem que descrever quais as possibilidades que vc tem em mãos, como o programa precisaria funcionar, qual seu ambiente, etc

Comment: Obs. eu gero vários emails utilizando o Interop do outlook é muito simples.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11223462/how-to-send-a-mail-using-microsoft-office-interop-outlook-mailitem-by-specifying

Você pode utilizar esse exemplo, criar o body em html, e enviar um relatório bem bacana.

Answer (score 1):

Recentemente fiz algo parecido para comparar dados, e para o mesmo usei `Except`, para me retornar apenas os novos registros em uma lista, vê se te atende:

```
/*Pego todas as descrições da minha lista(esta lista contem descrições novas e já cadastradas no BD)*/
var occurrencesDescription = model.CustomOccurrences.Select(o => o.Description).ToList();

/*Faço uma busca no BD usando as descrições(aqui ele só retornará as já cadastradas no BD)*/
var occurrences =repository.GetNonDeliveryReasonsListByDescriptionList(occurrencesDescription);

/*Uso o Except para me retornar apenas as que não foram localizadas na consulta acima*/
var newsOccurrences = model.CustomOccurrences.Select(o => o.Description).Except(occurrences.Select(o => o.Description)).ToList();
```

separada apenas as novas você trata como quiser, no meu caso eu cadastro novos registros.

Answer (score 0):

Caso você queira não cadastrar duplos sugiro que crie uma Trigger para o insert para validar se o registro já a existe e bloquear o insert. Mas se você quer somente enviar o mail no momento do insert, você tambem cria uma trigger porem com o codigo de envio de email, que é um pouco mais complicado mais nada de mais...

caso você use sql server aqui tem um um tutorial de como fazer ai basta implementar na trigger
https://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms190437(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Mas não vai ficar muito pesado ? REsolvi pra fazer uma trigger para vrificar somente os casos que quero e jogar em outra tabela. Dessa tabela, pretendo jogar via email.

Comment: Não fica pesado. Na empresa onde trabalho tem um caso que, quando uma determinado insert ocorre em uma tabela, ela dispara a trigger que insere a informação em uma tabela de log e desta tabela de log, dependendo da regra, manda email para os responsaveis, este email é disparado da tabeal de log, assim não "sujo" a tabela principal, entendeu?